# When is StreetPass unlocked during SMT4?

Tags: streetpass, smt4

I know that SMT4 features street pass support that allows your demons to fuse with another players, but I am wondering when this unlocks. There isn't any information about it at the cathedral. Is it unlocked by default, at a certain level, or after beating a specific boss/story event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having progressed farther through the game, I found the streetPass unlocked by entering an area shortly after beating the minotaur (for me this happened around level 12)